# How can I print the string param passed to ast.literal_eval in case I get a ValueError('malformed string')?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to print the original string param passed to `ast.literal_eval(original_string)` In case I get a `ValueError('malformed string')`.

In my application, I call the `ast.literal_eval` in many occasions, all over the place.

Should I just use a wrapper function that catches and prints? or is there's some simple and cool python/ast trick I'm missing?

EDIT: I don't want to catch the error, just see the string.

Comment: do you want to catch the error or just see the string?

Comment: If you have a variable named `original_string` to pass to `ast.literal_eval`, you still have the same variable named `original_string` in the `except` statement. So… where's the problem?

Comment: @abarnert - so you're saying just write a wrapper function which catches and prints, right?

Comment: @ihadanny: Yeah, if you just want to print and ignore the error, a wrapper function is the way to go.

Comment: why don't you want to use  try except?

Comment: You'll have put the call to `ast.literal_eval` in a `try/except ValueError` either every time you call it or once inside a wrapper function. Again, in either case, in the `except` clause you could print the `original_string`.